# How can I get the LastRunTime for a report using the Business Objects Web Services SDK?

Tags: c#, business-objects, business-objects-sdk

I'm using the Business Objects Web Services SDK to access our Business Objects data. I've successfully got a list of reports, and from that found the `LastSuccessfulInstance` of a report that has been previously run. However, I can't seem to get the `LastRunTime` to be populated. When I do a query with no attributes specified it comes back as not set, and I get the same result when I ask for that attribute in particular. I've looked at the report itself and the instance and they both don't have this information. Does anyone know where I can get it from?

Here's my code (hacked from one of SAP's demos):

```
    var sessConnUrl = serviceUrl + "/session";
    var boConnection = new BusinessObjects.DSWS.Connection(sessConnUrl);
    var boSession = new Session(boConnection);

    // Setup the Enterprise Credentials used to login to the Enterprise System
    var boEnterpriseCredential = new EnterpriseCredential
                                     {
                                         Domain = cmsname,
                                         Login = username,
                                         Password = password,
                                         AuthType = authType
                                     };

    // Login to the Enterprise System and retrieve the SessionInfo
    boSession.Login(boEnterpriseCredential);


    /************************** DISPLAY INBOX OBJECTS *************************/

    // Retrieve the BIPlatform Service so it can be used to add the USER
    var biPlatformUrl = boSession.GetAssociatedServicesURL("BIPlatform");
    var boBiPlatform = BIPlatform.GetInstance(boSession, biPlatformUrl[0]);

    // Specify the query used to retrieve the inbox objects
    // NOTE: Adding a "/" at the end of the query indicates that we want to 
    //       retrieve the all the objects located directly under the inbox.
    //       Without the "/" Path operator, the inbox itself would be returned. 
    const string query = "path://InfoObjects/Root Folder/Reports/";

    // Execute the query and retrieve the reports objects
    var boResponseHolder = boBiPlatform.Get(query, null);
    var boInfoObjects = boResponseHolder.InfoObjects.InfoObject;

    // If the reports contains a list of objects, loop through and display them
    if (boInfoObjects != null) 
    {
        // Go through and display the list of documents
    foreach (var boInfoObject in boInfoObjects)
    {
            var report = boInfoObject as Webi;
            if (report == null)
                continue;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(report.LastSuccessfulInstanceCUID))
            {
                var instanceQuery = "cuid://<" + report.LastSuccessfulInstanceCUID + ">";
                var instanceResponseHolder = boBiPlatform.Get(instanceQuery, null);
                var instance = instanceResponseHolder.InfoObjects.InfoObject[0];

            }
        }
    }
```

Both `report.LastRunTimeSpecified` and `instance.LastRunTimeSpecified` are false and both `LastRunTime` are `01\01\0001`, but I can see a last run time in the Web Intelligence UI.

Comment: Question, is this code written in c#? because it might help to tag it as c#. As it is there is very few code for the business-objects sdk in c#

Comment: @apereira: Yes, it is. I've added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help from Ted Ueda at SAP support I figured it out. Not all the properties are populated by default you need to append `@*` to the query string to get everything, i.e. change the line:

```
const string query = "path://InfoObjects/Root Folder/Reports/";
```

to:

```
const string query = "path://InfoObjects/Root Folder/Reports/@*";
```